# Integrate a Rails application with Google Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I'm starting a new application I'd like to integrate with Google Apps.

I'd like to have users sign in through their Google accounts, and access Google APIs for their domain (list all domain users, and allow them to login and share the same data).

I've never done this, so I'm a bit confused what steps do I need to perform to do it, I've read some docs on the net, and I also gave a look at omniauth.

Requirements:

- only login through google apps account
- each user must login with its own user/pwd (google account @domain.com)
- all users of the same domain must see the same shared data (of course the app will take care what's public and what's not).

It seemed to me that all I need to have this working is:
 * integrate an OpenID client (such as omniauth)
 * when user confirms Google will redirect user to a callback on my application
 * I now have a token that I can use to query google APIs

Am I right?
I've also given a look through [this article](http://intridea.com/posts/easy-rails-admin-login-with-google-apps-and-omniauth) but it seems it's not what I'm searching for, I cannot know in advance what the user domain is.

Maybe I'm confusing gmail accounts with google apps accounts, using the latter will users be able to login with their own account or they will all share only one account for the whole domain?

Is `omniauth` the right gem to accomplish this kind of login?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the devise gem has some easy omniauth in it. not sure, though

Comment: Yeah, omniauth and devise can be ridicoulus easily integrated, by the way I only want to make users sign up with their google account, so Devise would be useless for me.

Answer (score 5):

Omniauth is the answer. I wrote a [gem that provides a rake task to bootstrap](https://github.com/deafgreatdane/google_oauth_calendar) all the gems, routes, controllers, etc to get an app authenticating against google. The gem gets you started at using the calendar APIs, but the other google apps work in a similar way.

Comment: I looked at the source code of your gem, great one! It's exactly what I need to, I think I'll use your gem to generate the files :)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much correct. Users will have a SSO with their google account and upon approval will be redirected back from the callback that you've set within Google API.

You'll want to use the `omniauth-openid` gem and if needed set your whitelisted domains.

Answer (score 0):

OmniAuth is going to be your best bet to auth via 3rd party and meet your requirements.  Have you given it a try?

Comment: It's hard to try it since all examples are assuming you've already integrated Devise or Authlogic, but I don't want to provide custom login information, all users must use their google account.